# Table of true/false totals after searching for strings

Tags: r

Here's a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(letters = letters) %>% mutate(letters = as.character(letters))
df[3,1] <- ""
df[5,1] <- ""
df[8,1] <- "Unknown"
```

I would like to return a table with two values, true or false, where true is the count of instances where either an empty string "" or string "Unknown" was found.

Here is my attempt:

```
which(table(df), names(table(df) %in% c("", "Unknown")))
```

Which gave an error:

```
Error in which(table(df), names(table(df) %in% c("", "Unknown"))) : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical
```

How can I search through a df column for any of the values within c() and to then return a table showing the count of any instance that was found of the form True: 3, False: 23?

Comment: `table(df$letters %in% c("", "Unknown"))`

Comment: You could also do `data.frame(letters, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` instead of loading dplyr for no reason

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out. Sometimes it's hard to snap out of dplyr after staring at r console for hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Ronak Shah in the comment, we can use

```
table(df$letters %in% c("", "Unknown"))
```

Comment: Have you copied comment @ Ronak Shah as an answer?? You should have given credit to him by mentioning his name.

Comment: You should have done as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304126/is-it-correct-to-answer-copying-from-comments-by-other-users) or [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304126/is-it-correct-to-answer-copying-from-comments-by-other-users)

Comment: My apologies to Ronak Shah, we must have submitted at the same time.  I was definitely not copying a comment as an answer to take credit.  I appreciate your concern @AaghazHussain